# C Initializing type defined structure pointers

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initialization, posix

Well, im having an issue initializing global defined type structures.

The typedefined is:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_t pthread;
    int status;
    int id;
    time_t entrada;
} Cliente;
```

And the global declaration im using is this:

```
Cliente *cola=malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
```

but the compiler says it has to be defined by one CONSTANT

The objetive is to have a dinamic array of Cliente type named cola.
If I dont initialize them well i get a segmentation fault at 0.00s of execution.
The reason to make this as a global variable its because is a resource shared among threads, i know is not the best practice but I am required to act like so.

I dont know how many Cliente would I have (could be a default number or one argv random input) so this is why I implemented and structure pointer.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since the initializer is not a constant expression, you have to perform the initialization within a function.

Comment: Tom Karzes, but how do i initialize an array structure pointer if i dont know exactly how much members would i need in it?

Comment: Well in your sample code you're trying to allocate space for exactly one.  You can certainly do the exact same thing from within a function.  But if in fact you wish to do something different from what's in your sample, then simply wait until you do know how many you want, and then allocate it as an array.  If that value changes, you can use `realloc` to increase the size of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define it on global scope and allocate memory for that before first use. For example:

```
Cliente* cola;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        perror("First arg indicates thread numbers and is required");
    }

    int thread_count = atoi(argv[1]);
    cola = malloc(sizeof(*cola) * thread_count);
    ...
    // Extend cola size without losing previous data
    cola = realloc(cola, sizeof(*cola) * (thread_count + x));
}
```